# Limit of $Y_n = \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right)^{1/n}$ for $n\to\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $P(X_1 = 1) = P(X_1 = 2) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $(Y_n)_{n\geq1}$ be defined as

$$Y_n = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right)^{1/n}$$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Show that there exists (and determine it) a real number $a$ such that $Y_n \to a$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Observe that: $$Y_{n}=2^{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ X_{i}=2\right\} }}$$
  where the $\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ X_{i}=2\right\} }$ are iid with Bernoulli
  distribution that has parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.
- If $a_n$ converges then so does $2^{a_n}$.
- SLLN

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(Y_n) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(X_i)}{n}$$

With strong law of large numbers $\log(Y_n)$ converges almost surely to $E(\log(X_1))$.
I let you do the computation of the expected value.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$(log($X_1$)) = $\frac{1}{2}$(log(1) + log(2), but I don't see why log($Y_n$) converges almost surely to $\mathbb{E}$(log($X_1$)).

Comment: The random varaibles $\log(X_1), \dots ,\log(X_n)$ are iid so you can apply strong law of large numbers thus $\log(Y_n) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(X_i)}{n}$ convers almost surely to $E(\log(X_1))$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at $\log (Y_n)$ and use the law of large numbers for $(\log(X_n))_{n\ge 1}$.